# What is the purpose of op-amp in the output of Instrumentation amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, instrumentation-amplifier

I encountered a problem while solving an analog circuit.
I just need to know the purpose of the last op-amp (K4) at this circuit:

[image]

while solving I understand it just amplify the output voltage from the Instrumentation Amplifier, but there is known purpose for it beside to amplify Vout3.

thanks!

Comment: Is this from EEG or EKG or EMG sensors?

Comment: it just a problem from my homework.
I know this kind of circuits very common so possibly it used in these sensors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

K4 produces amplification for AC signals whilst providing a DC amplification of 1 (so that DC levels are maintained from the InAmp output to whatever stage follows K4). It might also be used to share the burden of AC signal gain between InAmp and itself thus minimizing slew rate problems in the InAmp.

Comment: So - the last stage acts as a sort of highpass.

Comment: @LvW are you asking or saying!

Comment: @Andy aka...there is no question mark. Hence, it is not a question. To me, the transfer function [1+sR2C/(1+sR1C)] is a highpass with a fixed gain of unity at low frequencies. Why are you asking?

Comment: @LvW it's always best to be careful!!